# Prove that if $M$ is maximal ideal of $S$ and $\varphi$ is surjective then $\varphi^{-1}\left( M\right) $ is maximal ideal of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I'm thinking of Dummit Abstract Algebra, Chap 7, sectin 4, exercise 13b. I've tried to show that 
$R/\varphi^{-1}\left(  M\right)  $ is division ring, but was not successful. Can anybody help me?

Let $\varphi:R\rightarrow S$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings.

(a) If $P$ is a prime ideal of $S$, then either $\varphi^{-1}\left(  P\right)
=R$ or $\varphi^{-1}\left(  P\right)  $ is prime. OK!

(b) Prove that if $M$ is maximal ideal of $S$ and $\varphi$ is surjective, then
$\varphi^{-1}\left(  M\right)  $ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $\pi:S\to S/M$ is the natural map, then $\pi\circ\phi$ is surjective, and
$$ \ker(\pi\circ\phi)=\{x\in R:\pi(\phi(x))=0\}=\{x\in R:\phi(x)\in M\}=\phi^{-1}(M)$$

Therefore $R/\phi^{-1}(M)\simeq S/M$ by the first isomorphism theorem, so if $M$ is a maximal ideal then $S/M$ is a field, hence $R/\phi^{-1}(M)$ is a field, hence $\phi^{-1}(M)$ is a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I tried working with a more complex solution but ignoring isomorphism theorems.
Suppose $J $ is an ideal of $R$ and $\phi^{-1}(M) \subset J \subseteq R$. Then there exists $x \in J \setminus\phi^{-1}(M) $. This means that $\phi(x)\notin M$ and, since $M$ is a maximal ideal of $S$, $\langle\phi(x),M\rangle=S$. Now consider a random $y \in R$. I want to prove that $y \in J$. $\phi(y) \in S=\langle\phi(x),M\rangle\Rightarrow\phi(y)=s*\phi(x)+\overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}s_{i}*m_{i}$ where $s,s_i \in S, m_i \in M$. As $\phi $ is surjective I can write: $\phi(y)=\phi(r)*\phi(x)+\widetilde m$ where $r \in R, \overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}s_{i}*m_{i}=\widetilde m \in M $. The last means that $\phi(y-r*x)=\widetilde m \in M$. So $y-r*x \in \phi^{-1}(M) \subset J$ and as $ x\in J$, it is also $ y \in J.$ So we proved that any ideal $J$, containing $M$, is equal to $R$. So $M$ is maximal.